# Laravel 5.2 Save relationship BelongsTo One To Many

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hi I have `User Model` like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'role_id',
        'email',
        'password',
        'full_name',
        'address',
        'phone',
        'family_name',
        'family_address',
        'family_phone',
        'idcard',
        'status',
        'balance',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
```

and I have `Post Model` like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'title',
        'content',    
    ];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);    
    }
}
```

and in my `Posts Controller`

```
public function store(CreatePostRequest $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    $post = Post::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'content' => $request->content,        
    ]);

    $post->user()->associate($user);

    return redirect()->route('admin.posts.index')->with('success', 'Post berhasil disimpan.');
}
```

I get this error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`rentcar`.`posts`, CONSTRAINT `posts_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `posts` (`title`, `content`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Judul, <p>Isi</p>, 2016-10-20 11:10:31, 2016-10-20 11:10:31))
```

What wrong with my store method code?

In case I want to save post and associate it with current logged in user, how should my code looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `create` method immediately saves.

So either you assign the user_id in the create array, or you use

```
$post = new Post();
$post->title = $request->title;
$post->content = $request->content;

$post->user()->associate($user);

$post->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your foreign key in posts table is nullable.

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
public function store(CreatePostRequest $request)
{
   $user = Auth::user();

$post = Post::create([
    'title' => $request->title,
    'content' => $request->content,   
    'user_id' => $user->id;     
]);

return redirect()->route('admin.posts.index')->with('success', 'Post berhasil disimpan.');
 }
```